# Function keeps resetting everytime I scroll past trigger point

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a function which triggers on scroll to a certain point, the function works but somehow keeps resetting everytime i scroll further down, is there any way to only fire it when it reaches that certain point and that certain point alone?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

function someFunction() {
$(".someContent .someYellowOverlay").toggleClass("someAnimation").delay(250).queue(function(next){
$(this).css("transform-origin", "right center");
next();
}).delay(125).queue(function(next){
$("p").css("display", "block");
next();
}).delay(250).queue(function(next){
$(this).removeClass("someAnimation");
next();
})
}

$(document).scroll(function(){

var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
console.log(scrollPos)

if (scrollPos >= 250) {
  someFunction();
  setTimeout();
}

})
})
```

https://codepen.io/alexyap/pen/jmQqvQ?editors=0110

Comment: Well, you're calling it when `scrollPos >= 250`. So it will always call past that point. If you want it to only fire once ever, you could set a flag the first time it's run, or change the condition to something like `scrollPos >= 250 && scrollPos <= 255` to fire only within a thin range.

Comment: thank you this solved everything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a flag that gets set the first time the scroll is greater than or equal to 250, and reset it when the scroll is less than 250 (that way if the user scrolls down, back up, and down again, it will still trigger again).

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var flag = false;

function someFunction() {
  $(".someContent .someYellowOverlay").toggleClass("someAnimation").delay(250).queue(function(next    ) {
    $(this).css("transform-origin", "right center");
    next();
  }).delay(125).queue(function(next) {
    $("p").css("display", "block");
    next();
  }).delay(250).queue(function(next) {
    $(this).removeClass("someAnimation");
    next();
  });
}

$(document).scroll(function(){
  var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
  console.log(scrollPos)

  if (scrollPos >= 250 && flag === false) {
    flag = true;
    someFunction();
    setTimeout();
  } else if (scrollPos < 250) {
    flag = false;
  }
});

});
```

If you want the event to happen once and only once, then you can simply remove the extra `else if` condition or you could look into using jQuery's [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method which will make sure the event only happens once.

(Note you can name the flag variable something more descriptive to your liking, such as didScroll or scrolledGreaterThan250)

Comment: this is perfect! thanks! although the previous solution was okay this is better

Answer (score 0):

It is keep resetting because it is always firing, 
I suggest adding global variable, 
in my case i called it doAnimate, 
It will check if the animation is true trigger if not meaning it already triggered, i will reset whenever we scrol to the top.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var doAnimate = true;
function someFunction() {
if(doAnimate){
$(".someContent.someYellowOverlay")
.toggleClass("someAnimation").delay(250).queue(function(next){
    $(this).css("transform-origin", "right center");
    next();
  }).delay(125).queue(function(next){
    $("p").css("display", "block");
    next();
  }).delay(250).queue(function(next){
    $(this).removeClass("someAnimation");
    next();
  })
}
doAnimate = false;
}

var flag = false;
$(document).scroll(function(){

var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
console.log(scrollPos)

if (scrollPos >= 250 && flag === false) {
flag = true;
someFunction();
} 
// when it reach the top again  reset all 
if(scrollPos == 0)
  {
 flag = false;
  $("p").css("display", "none");
    doAnimate = true;
  }
})
})
```